# TargetException on Invoke

Tags: c#, dictionary, delegates, invoke

I have a problem with my `Invoke()` throwing a TargetException.

```
public Controller(SystemUI ui, System system)
{
    UI = ui;
    System = system;

    UI.CommandEntered += ParseCommand;

    Commands = new Dictionary<string, Delegate>();
    Commands.Add(":q", new Action(UI.Close));   
}
```

I then call `Commands[input[0]].Method.Invoke(this, input.ToArray<object>());`, but it throws a TargetException with the message

> Object does not match target type.

Do I need a cast?
I'm quite lost, and I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: What UI framework/platform is this?

Comment: As the error is trying to tell you, you're trying to invoke a method on the wrong type.  Check your types

Comment: What's the signature of the method in question? You're trying to pass an array of objects to it. Is that correct? Check your method name, etc. Does UI.Close() take an array of objects as its parameter, assuming that input[0] = ":q"?

Comment: @Dai It's a ConsoleApplication.

Comment: @ManoDestra Yes, I'm trying to pass an array of strings to it, that's true. UI.Close() takes no parameters. I have a bunch of commands in the dictionary, all of them throw the exception.

Comment: Well, that's almost certainly your issue then. You're trying to pass an array of objects to a method that takes no parameters. Try changing `input.toArray<object>()` to just `new object[0]` or `new object[] {}`

Comment: @ManoDestra I don't know why I didn't see that. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on comments above, you are trying to invoke an Action (UI.Close), but you are passing an array of objects as parameters to this action, which has no parameters therefore incurring this exception.

Change...

```
input.toArray<object>()
```

to...

```
new object[0], or new object[] {} // or perhaps even just null may do the trick.
```